# Is giving $20 cash on hand supposed to contain interest?

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance

Each year on her birthday, Jane’s parents put \$20 into an investment account earning $9\frac{1}{2}$% per annum compound interest. The first deposit took place on the day of her birth. On her 18th birthday, Jane’s parents gave her the account and \$20 cash in hand. How much money did she receive from her parents on her 18th birthday?

So $$A_n =  20\frac{1.095^n-1}{0.095}$$

However, I am unsure what to make of the twenty cash on hand. I think it is 20 dollars on top of the account so $A_{18} + 20$. However the answers suggest simply $A_{19}=970$ but then that is $20$ **including interest on the final 20** right? $A_{19}$ factors in the "20 dollars cash in hand" but since $A_0 = 20(1.095)$, that final "20 dollars cash in hand" would have interest applied to it which doesn't seem implied in the question.

I am unsure at this stage

Comment: $A_1 = 20,$ the amount in the account immediately after the deposit on the day Jane is born. $A_2$ is the amount immediately after the deposit on her first birthday. Suppose instead of the confusing "cash in hand", Jane's parents deposit the usual $\$20$ on her eighteenth birthday and then immediately withdraw the entire amount of the account and give it to Jane. Jane gets the same amount of money as in the original problem statement, doesn't she?

Comment: The notation is badly chosen in my opinion. It would make more sense to say $A_n =  20\dfrac{1.095^{n+1}-1}{0.095}$ so that you can start with $A_0$ as the balance on Jane's birthday and $A_k$ as the balance after the deposit on Jane's $k$th birthday. But then the question is whether Jane's parents made a deposit on Jane's $18$th birthday before withdrawing the balance, in addition to giving Jane $20$ "cash in hand". For the formula as I wrote it, $A_{18}$ is the balance *after* a deposit made that same day, so if the cash in hand is instead of a deposit, the balance is only $A_{18}-20.$

Comment: what does $9\,12\%$ interest mean?  Did you mean to write $9.5$?

Comment: The problem is also ambiguous because it says there is a deposit every year on Jane's birthday -- what about Jane's eighteenth birthday? Surely there is an opportunity to make a deposit that day before withdrawing the balance and giving it to Jane, *in addition* to the "cash in hand", but the "official" answer seems to imply that no such deposit is made. How are we supposed to know this?

Comment: The question of lulu is still pending.

Comment: sorry, it was 9.12%. Ive fixed

Comment: @DavidK I believe she doesnt get the deposit on her birthday since they have already given Jane the account on her 18th birthday (and perhaps also since they are given her 20 cash instead)

Comment: If it's $9.12\%$, where does $1.095$ come from?

Comment: I am so so sorry. It is actually **$9\frac{1}{2}$%**, so yes @lulu you are right

Comment: @user71207 I think your idea about what happens on Jane's 18th birthday is what was **intended** by the author of the question. But if the bank opens at 9 am, Jane's parents could make a deposit at 10 am and then give the account to Jane at 11 am. Technically that also would satisfy the wording of the problem. I think the intention was that "Each year on her birthday" should be interpreted as "On the day of her birth and each year on her birthday up to and including her seventeenth birthday," but that is not what the problem statement says.

Comment: My previous comments are really a critique of the problem statement you received, not your interpretation of it. True, you misunderstood the (confusing) numbering of the $A_n$ amounts, but your interpretation that there was no deposit on Jane's 18th birthday is what I also would assume if someone assigned this problem to me. And then, because I am annoying, I would complain about the ambiguity, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

In this annuity calculation, the accumulated value of the annuity is to be calculated **on the date of the last payment**.  That makes it an **ordinary annuity**, as opposed to an **annuity due**, where the value is found one period after the last payment.

So just use the formula for an the accumulated value of an ordinary annuity lasting 19 years with 19 annual payments of $20, the first made one year after the annuity "starts", and the last made 19 years after the annuity "starts".

The framers of the question confused things by having payments made on the exact dates of the **first** and **last** payments. There is no standard formula for such a scheme although one could be created quite easily.

It may seem contradictory to consider the annuity "starts" a year before Jane was born (or even conceived!).  But in. for example, a home mortgage, you take out a loan, receive the amount of the loan (!) and the mortgage starts, but you don't make the first payment until one period has passed.